# Can I install a wall valve for a refrigerator water line?

Tags: refrigerator, fitting, copper-tubing

My refrigerator sits in an alcove and is getting is getting surrounding cabinets.  I ripped out the sheetrock behind it, and plan on replacing it with 3/4 plywood to make the cabinets easier to hang, and in the process, I'm cleaning up some electrical, running some wiring, new insulation, etc....

One thing I'd really like to fix is the refrigerator water line which previously ran through a hole in the floor.  I would like to know if there is a clean way to put it behind the wall with some type of 1/4" spigot.  I'd also like to tee it if possible to have another line for a plumbed coffee maker.  Is there anything like this on the market?

Comment: Just to save you some time... have you ever looked at hanging the cabinets on a french cleat?  Sort this is off-topic, but ripping out all the drywall just for stronger backing *behind* what should already be a pretty rigid box (the cabinet), sounds like some serious overkill.  Always hang cabinets directly on studs, not drywall.  French cleats are a great way to do this.  (Food for though - I know you didn't ask so hopefully I'm not overstepping or being useless!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, since you are working on the walls anyway, you can install something [like this box](https://www.homedepot.com/p/SharkBite-1-2-in-Push-to-Connect-Brass-Ice-Maker-Outlet-Box-25032/205545050):

[image]

Depending on the new layout of your kitchen, you can connect to a pipe coming up from below (through the floor), but if you have cabinets (i.e., no open space) between the refrigerator alcove and the sink, you could run the pipe from the sink instead, going under the cabinets (behind the toe kick) instead of under the floor.

Comment: Though depending on how deep that box is, the water tube coming from it will be coming straight out, and usually refrigerators are pushed all the way back to the wall, possibly crunching the valve and pushing it backwards, since there will be no room for the water tube to bend with the fridge pushing right up to it.  I'm sure there's a way to work around the spacing issues, but if you use something like this, be careful, as you don't want an undiscovered leak behind your fridge.

Comment: @Milwrdfan All true. But I think the basic idea is a recessed box like that is a lot better than a bare pipe running down to the floor (like I have in my house...)

Comment: Every junction in a supply line is a place where failure can occur.   I have the bare copper pipe (with about 6 feet coiled behind the fridge for moving) that goes straight to a water pipe.

Comment: I think this will work.  I was looking for a solution that didn’t require adaptors on both ends.  But maybe I’ll just re-run the line with .5”

Comment: I suggest the OP does themself a favor and put a shutoff in an accessible (ie, don’t have to pull the fridge) location.

Comment: The valve can probably be swiveled to the side a bit (or 90 degrees to the side if there are detents) to make the line lay flatter to the wall.